# Handle legends overflow in Highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to set the maximum width of the entire Highstock legends component? Note that I'm not looking for the `itemWidth` option for each legend, but a way to handle the entire element.

My legends are in the top right corner, like so:

```
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    floating: true
},
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmsgutLc/

Now if you decrease the width of the window, the legends will end up overlapping other components of the chart (in this case, the title). What I am looking for is a way to stack them on multiple rows when needed, to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment the highcharts supports only [width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.width) parameter, not maximum width. In other cases you need to [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) function and  prepare your own solution.